# Relation between curl of vector field and and its derivative in the normal direction

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, vectors

I have been trying to prove this equivalence but I could not manage to do it. I have used all kinds of identities with no success.

I want to prove that, being $\mathbf n$ a unit surface normal vector, the expression

$$  \nabla \times \mathbf A = \mathbf k \times \mathbf n   $$

is equivalent to

$$    \frac{\partial \mathbf A }{\partial n} =-\mathbf k    $$

Note that I am not sure if the equivalence actually holds.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: As @Rahul has proved with a counterexample the equivalence does not hold. Rafa has found that his proof is flawed because the incorrent elimination of the Levi-Civita symbol. I will try to understand things better and keep posting.

Comment: I'll repost my counterexample here since it's on a deleted answer: For $\mathbf A(x,y,z)=(z,0,−x)$, $\mathbf n=(0,0,1)$, $\mathbf k=(−2,0,0)$ we have $∇×\mathbf A=(0,2,0)=\mathbf k×\mathbf n$, but $∂\mathbf A/∂\mathbf n=(1,0,0)=−\frac12\mathbf k$. Maybe there is an additional condition that $\mathbf A\cdot\mathbf n=0$ on the surface?

Comment: Hi @Rahul... Yes ! This condition holds. In fact also $\mathbf A \times \mathbf n = \mathbf0$ on the surface. As far as I can see, this gives $\mathbf A = \mathbf 0$ on the surface. What puzzled me was the fact that actually $\mathbf A $ is $\Delta \mathbf A$; this is, the actual vector $\mathbf A$ is the difference between values at both sides of the surface. Would you write the answer?